# How to detect the layout error?

Tags: android

How to detect the layout error ? if i start the eclipse and open the first Activity with layout. but the first Activity.java file is gave some error in the SetContentView(R.layout.main) .am using latest Sdk API 16.

```
package com.eConnect.Restaurant;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
     return true;
  }
}
```

main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#000000"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
    android:src="@drawable/econnect_logo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
    android:text="@string/uid"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:hint="@string/uid"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textColor="#9966cc" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
    android:text="@string/PW"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:hint="@string/PW"
    android:inputType="numberPassword"
    android:textColor="#9966cc" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
    android:background="#cccccc"
    android:text="@string/bt"
    android:textColor="#006600"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

androidmanifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.eConnect.Restaurant"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

  <application
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
     <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What error? Please post the logcat output!

Comment: Just build your project once.

Comment: akshay how to avoid the physical keypad in android emulater in eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First clean your project.By using Project > Clean.Another thing you have to do is delete  R.Java from list.Again clean the project.Try this one and let me know.

Comment: our R.java file is not displayed after delete and clean wat i do

Comment: @CharuPriya What error you are getting in your xml file or logcat or console ?

Comment: @CharuPriya Now what error you are having in your ErroLog or in xml file?

Comment: i have some pbm in the another layout.i am used the edittext inside the multi Column custom listView, bt i cant able to select the listView items.bcos the list items are cant clickable.

Comment: @CharuPriya You can set the listener for your listView by using setOnClickListener(). And another thing you have to ask it in separate question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Build your project once.I also face this but when i build my project the error vanishes

Comment: In your eclipse environment u can see options like file ,edit,run...Similarly there is option Build in that u select build project.

Comment: let me know the status after u build your project

Comment: if i create ne xml file no contents are avail.oly below code only avail.<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"></menu>

Comment: if i open the new xml file no default contents are available

Comment: s .then if i open the new xml file no default contents are available

Comment: See wen u create a new android xml file in layout folder u can see only the linearlayout then u need to add widgets to it

Comment: ok no pbm abt that. but nw the firstActivity detect our xml file like main cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: can u tell me the name of xml file in your layout folder?

Comment: I think ur main xml file has not been generated in R.java file

Comment: Is R.java file created in your gen folder.If yes delete it and again clean and build ur project.If not send me ur project in my email id